# Есть ли API для игрового руля? С#

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли как то Взаимодействовать с Рулем и педалями  (в частности Логитех 29) посредством С#? узнать угол поворота руля, либо нажатие педали газа?

Comment: Unity умеет, значит можно как-то.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.racingwheel?view=winrt-22000

Answer (score 0):

А он вообще нужен? Посмотри в сторону `mmsystem.h` там есть полный функционал для работы с джойстиками

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-joystick-functions
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-joystick-messages

Я уже молчу про Direct Input там вообще всё проще некуда.

**=== Добавлено спустя ===**

Вот прям подарок от узкоглазых товарищей.

- https://github.com/tuyiherizon/TableModifier/tree/master/KeyChanger/Joysticks